# how can i set radio button checked base after fetching the value

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm making a simple fetch and update.

How can I set radio button checked base on the value I fetch on the postgresDB?

I already fetch few data's on postgresDB

```
$item['itemtype'];

echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" value=\"Ingredient\" <?php if(isset($item[itemtype]) && $item[itemtype] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked=\"checked\"'; ?>>";
echo "<label for=\"radio\">Ingredient</label>";
echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" value=\"Miscellaneous\" <?php if(isset($item[itemtype]) && $item[itemtype] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked=\"checked\"'; ?>>";
echo "<label for=\"radio\">Miscellaneous</label>";
echo "</td>";
```

type's of itemtype

- Ingredient
- Miscellaneous

and how should I validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
<?php
$item['itemtype'] = "Ingredient";

echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" value=\"Ingredient\"";
if(isset($item[itemtype]) && $item[itemtype] == 'Ingredient')
    echo "checked=checked";
echo ">Ingredient";

echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" value=\"Miscellaneous\"";
if(isset($item[itemtype]) && $item[itemtype] == 'Miscellaneous')
    echo "checked=checked";
echo ">Miscellaneous";

?>
```

Comment: im getting errors `NOTICE: Use of undefined constant itemtype - assumed 'itemtype' in D:\Wamp\wamp\www\Php\CTea\UpdateItem.php on line 235`